# Is that possible to allow my page be framed, but only by the specified origin?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, browser, frame

I am interested in this issue [What exactly can an IFrame do with the top.Location object (cross-domain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113902/what-exactly-can-an-iframe-do-with-the-top-location-object-cross-domain).

I want to find a way to defense [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) recently, and I find this [solution](https://www.codemagi.com/blog/post/194).

However, this solution will forbid any page to iframe my page, and what I want is to allow some site in the **white list** can iframe my page.

I know the **Allow-From** of [X-Frame-Options](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/) can achieve my goal, but IE 6 and IE 7 doesn't support this feature.

Is that possible to allow my page be framed, but only by the specified origin?

**UPDATE**
@Padrig
Thanks for answering my question.
I can't comment on your answer right now, so I have to edit my question.

I have try your solution, but it can't work.

http://www.b.com/poc/beframed.html

```
<script>
    if (self === top) || (top.location.hostname == 'www.a.com')) {
        alert(1);
    } 
</script>
```

http://www.a.com/poc/framer.html

```
<iframe src="http://www.b.com/poc/beframed.html"></iframe>
```

And my host file:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 www.a.com
> 127.0.0.1 www.b.com
> ```

There is no alert in my Chrome browser.

Comment: Oops I missed out a bracket: if ((self === top

Comment: I just add the left bracket, it still can't work:(

Comment: Sorry, I missed a very important point. See my new reply below. No more late night coding for me!

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Javascript doesn't allow one frame to access the properties of another frame in a different domain.

Yes it's possible, but but using document.referrer.